# Do Java arrays have a maximum size?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a limit to the number of elements a Java array can contain? If so, what is it?

Comment: You've accepted a wrong answer, just try to allocate such a long array (and no, I'm not running out of memory).

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878309/java-array-with-more-than-4gb-elements

Comment: The right answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Using

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

... on MacOS, the answer seems to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2`.  Once you go beyond that:

```
cat > Foo.java << "END"
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] array = new boolean[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1]; // too big
  }
}
END
java -Xmx4g Foo.java
```

... you get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
  Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Comment: I think the idea of downvotes makes no sense unless we are willing to downvote answers that are plain and simply _wrong_.  Does the difference of five bytes actually matter in the real world, NO, of course not. But it concerns me that people are willing to give an answer "authoritatively" without even trying it to see if it really works.

As for the memory limit, well, DUH.  That's like if you asked me "how many grapes can you eat?" and I said "well, it depends on how many I have in the fridge at the time."

Comment: Sry I'm not understanding your answer.. do you mean to say that the maximum is MAX_VALUE - 5 even if my machine has the required memory to create an int the size of MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: @Pacerier, yes, the memory address index is 32bit and there is an object header+length, so they still need to be addressed by that 32bit index.

Comment: Do you happen to know _why_ it won't give you those five bytes? Is this necessarily something that always happens in Java, or could it just be related to your computer's memory or something?

Comment: @Kevin Bourrillion: This seems to have changed, using Oracle 1.7.0_07 I can allocate up to `MAX_VALUE-2` elements. This is independent of what I allocate, and I really wonder what can the VM use the two "things" for (the length doesn't fit in 2 bytes).

Comment: @bestsss: I don't think so... there may be only 2 spare bytes (see my above comment) and the object header is much bigger. Actually, the JVM can use unsigned ints, so there must be some other reason.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion: Well the five bytes do actually matter in the real world, since you cannot even instance the array (independant of the objects in it).

Comment: @maaartinus, *the object header is much bigger* Object header is (usually) 8bytes+4bytes length. References take 4 bytes on 32bit systems.

Comment: Wait, it runs out of memory. What if you just give it more memory? I want to know about the maximum length without that restraint. In C and Objective C, when you get the array's length, it's represented as a long.

Comment: Does this limit also apply on strings?

Comment: @TomášZato the latest at `Integer.MAX_VALUE+1`, you will have an integer overflow. Array sizes in Java are `int`, not `long`; no matter what data type you store in your array, bytes or references. Strings are just Object references.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand this - so does string happen to be encapsulated array of chars or not?

Comment: The maximum number of elements in an array in JDK 6 and above is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` = 2 147 483 645. Java successfully allocates such an array if you run it with `-Xmx13G`. It fails with `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` if you pass `-Xmx12G`.

Comment: int arr[] = new int[1000000000]; gives `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: I guess that future readers may be interested to run eyes over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189656/how-properly-discover-the-maximun-size-allowed-for-an-array

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov You mean an int array right? Testing in Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0), jdk1.8.0_221, I got the same result for an int array, setting the options in a run configuration for the test class, although jvisualvm shows 8GB heap space allocated to the test process. For a boolean array I didn't need to set run config options for the test class with -Xmx1024m set in eclipse.ini, and jvisualvm shows 2GB heap space allocated to the test process.

Comment: @avg I don't remember; likely I was allocating an array of `int`. The required heap size depends on the JVM and chosen GC. Additionally, `boolean` is four times smaller than `int`, and it may be compressed to store 8 values in one byte.

Comment: I've finally edited the answer with the more current value. 10 entire years after posting it. Thanks @maaartinus and others.

Answer (score 147):

This is (of course) totally VM-dependent.

Browsing through the source code of OpenJDK 7 and 8 [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l190), [`.Hashtable`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java#l367), [`.AbstractCollection`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l193),  [`.PriorityQueue`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#l263), and [`.Vector`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Vector.java#l245), you can see this **claim** being repeated:

> ```
> /**
>  * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
>  * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
>  * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
>  */
> private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
> ```

which is added by Martin Buchholz (Google) [on 2010-05-09](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/ec45423a4700#l3.1); reviewed by Chris Hegarty (Oracle).

So,  *probably*  we can say that the maximum "safe" number would be  **2 147 483 639** (`Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`) and "attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)".

(Yes, Buchholz's standalone claim does not include backing evidence, so this is a calculated [appeal to authority.](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority) Even within OpenJDK itself, we can see code like [`return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/ec45423a4700#l4.50) which shows that `MAX_ARRAY_SIZE` does not yet have a *real* use.)

Comment: And why we need to add `-8`?

Comment: @Pacerier. Shouldn't this MAX_ARRAY_SIZE be applied only when you are using an ArrayList? That is different from using an array like int[] array = new int[some_value_here]; isn't it? Why can a constant defined in ArrayList be applied to a normal array (defined with [])? Are they the same  behind the scenes?

Comment: @Tiago, No, the code itself has got nothing to do with the maximum size of arrays. It's just a claim.

Comment: @JohnWinter, The quote states "Some VMs reserve some header words in an array". So the `-8` is due to the bytes the reserved header words would occupy.

Comment: @Pacerier 2^31 (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8, approximate) * 2^2 (assume 4 byte int) = 2 ^ 33. But I think 64-bit system have at least 48 bit for their virtual address space. A portion of virtual address space goes to heap segment, so it seems the array in Java can get much larger than this size. Am I missing anything?

Comment: not "totally". No matter the JVM's limits, it'll have to work with indices being int - thus, no index larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE is possible.

Answer (score 39):

There are actually two limits.  One, the maximum element indexable for the array and, two, the amount of memory available to your application.  Depending on the amount of memory available and the amount used by other data structures, you may hit the memory limit before you reach the maximum addressable array element.

Comment: This answer doesn't attempt to answer what the value of "the maximum element indexable for the array" is.

Answer (score 32):

Going by this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays:

> Java has been criticized for not supporting arrays of more than 2<sup>31</sup>−1 (about 2.1 billion) elements. This is a limitation of the language; the Java Language Specification, Section 10.4, states that:
>
> > Arrays must be indexed by int values... An attempt to access an array
> >     component with a long index value results in a compile-time error.

Supporting large arrays would also require changes to the JVM. This limitation manifests itself in areas such as collections being limited to 2 billion elements and the inability to memory map files larger than 2 GiB. Java also lacks true multidimensional arrays (contiguously allocated single blocks of memory accessed by a single indirection), which limits performance for scientific and technical computing.

Comment: Java lacks the syntactic sugar for multidimensional arrays, but you can still "have" them with a little bit of multiplication (unless the total size of the array exceeded the aforementioned limit)

Comment: @kbolino It's true. I'm sure the scientific users are smart enough to make their own multi-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 15):

Arrays are non-negative integer indexed , so maximum array size you can access would be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. The other thing is how big array you can create. It depends on the maximum memory available to your JVM and the content type of the array. Each array element has it's size, example. `byte` = 1 byte, `int` = 4 bytes, `Object` reference = 4 bytes (on a 32 bit system).

So if you have 1 MB of memory available on your machine, you could allocate an array of `byte[1024 * 1024]` or `Object[256 * 1024]`.

*Answering your question* - You can allocate an array of size (maximum available memory / size of array item).

*Summary* - Theoretically the maximum size of an array will be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Practically it depends on how much memory your JVM has and how much of that has already been allocated to other objects.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to create a byte array like this

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE-x];
System.out.println(bytes.length);
```

With this run configuration:

```
-Xms4G -Xmx4G
```

And java version:

> Openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b16)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b16, mixed mode)

It only works for x >= 2 which means the maximum size of an array is Integer.MAX_VALUE-2

Values above that give

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
>       at Main.main(Main.java:6)

Answer (score 2):

Maximum number of elements of an `array` is `(2^31)−1` or `2 147 483 647`

Comment: Java can't allocate array of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1`, you'll get "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit". The maximum number of elements in JDK 6 and above is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2` = 2 147 483 645.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there limit on java array. Java uses an integer as an index to the array and the maximum integer store by JVM is 2^32. so you can store 2,147,483,647 elements in the array.

In case you need more than max-length you can use two different arrays but the recommended method is store data into a file. because storing data in the file has no limit. because files stored in your storage drivers but array are stored in JVM. JVM provides limited space for program execution.

Comment: Other answers indicated it's not possible to allocate an array of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` even if you have memory available.

Comment: 2^32 is not 2,147,483,647 (which is 2^31 - 1)

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's java limitation caping it at 2^30-4 being 1073741820. Not 2^31-1. Dunno why but i tested it manually on jdk. [2^30-3 still throwing vm except](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRGQy.jpg)

Edit: fixed -1 to -4, checked on windows jvm

Comment: You're using a 32-bit JVM. Use a 64-bit JVM and the JVM limit will be close to 2^31. (You also need heap space available, which is not the default, and will be affected by your physical memory.)

Answer (score -1):

Java array has a limit because its a integer array, what meant it has up to 2,147,483,647 elements in array