# How to store, sort and group items (list/set/map) in java?

Tags: java, sorting, grouping, store

Given such data

```
UserID, MovieType , year 
1, 2, 2000
1, 3, 2000 
1, 2, 2006
2, 3, 2010
2, 4, 2011
2, 3, 2002
1, 2, 2010
```

What are the best option to store it in java , such that I can sort it according to first column , then second column then third ?

```
UserID, MovieType , year 
1, 2, 2000
1, 2, 2006
1, 2, 2010
1, 3, 2000 
2, 3, 2002
2, 3, 2010
2, 4, 2011
```

And then group them by user ID and Movietype

```
UserID, MovieType , movies seen per year  
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 1 
2, 3, 2
2, 4, 1
```

Comment: you are looking for generic soln where you can change the groupby etc or just for this particular problem?

Comment: Currently particular bur learning a general sol would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very specific solution, you could have a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>`.

The first Map stores UserIDs to a map that stores MovieTypes to MoviesSeenPerYear.

If you use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) as the underlying types, everything will automatically be numerically sorted.

This will not be very flexible, though - for example, it would be difficult if you wanted to re-sort by MovieType instead of UserId.

---

In response to your comment:

You will have 2 main limitations:

1. All of the Java collections classes are based on `int` sizes (same as the Java's array indexer), which have a maximum size of [just under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size) 2^31-1, or 2,147,483,647 - or just over 2 billion entries.
2. Memory limitations of your JVM / machine.

If you're looking at working with this much data, and would like more flexible sorting requirements, you'd be well advised to use an actual database - either one of the standard ones, or even a JVM-embedded one like [H2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_%28DBMS%29) or [Apache Derby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby).

Comment: I new in java and come across      SortedSet set = new TreeSet(); map is better option ?

Comment: @tnaser - A Set only stores items - without having keys/values to store associations.  A Map has keys/values to store associations.  If you want to use my solution, you need the TreeMap to store the key/value associations.  However, both a TreeMap and a TreeSet allow a custom comparator to be provided as part of its constructor.  You could actually use this with Fortunato's answer (+1 from me!).  By using the Set instead of a List with this, you wouldn't need to call `Collections.sort` at all - the Set would automatically sort itself and keep itself sorted.

Comment: Is there any limitations on size of Set, Map , List ? for example millions of data ?

Answer (score 2):

You should make a class that contains the three pieces of data. Then make an implementation of `Comparator`. 
So for example if in the data-containing class you have three getters such as `int getUserId()`, `int getMovieType()` and `int getYear()`.
You can then store the data objects in a `List` and sort this list using your comparator together with `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<T> comparator)`.

The comparator should do something like:

```
public int compare(DataObject data1, DataObject data2) {
   int comparison = data1.getUserId() - data2.getUserId();
   if (comparison == 0) {
       comparison = data1.getMovieType() - data2.getMovieType();
       if (comparison == 0) {
           comparison = data1.getYear() - data2.getYear();
       }
   }
   return comparison;
}
```

Comment: Actually for the sorting you want to do there would be only one comparator which would compare on the three pieces on data, one at a time. See the edit in the answer...