# Why doesn't String switch statement support a null case?

Tags: java, switch-statement, language-design

I am just wondering why the Java 7 `switch` statement does not support a `null` case and instead throws `NullPointerException`? See the commented line below (example taken from [the Java Tutorials article on `switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)):

```
{
    String month = null;
    switch (month) {
        case "january":
            monthNumber = 1;
            break;
        case "february":
            monthNumber = 2;
            break;
        case "march":
            monthNumber = 3;
            break;
        //case null:
        default: 
            monthNumber = 0;
            break;
    }

    return monthNumber;
}
```

This would have avoided an `if` condition for null check  before every `switch` use.

Comment: No conclusive answer to this, since we're not the people who made the language.  All answers will be pure conjecture.

Comment: An attempt to switch on `null` will cause an exception. Perform an `if` check for `null`, then go into the `switch` statement.

Comment: Re: conjecture: It has taken more than ten years for this feature to land. I am sure there is ample discussion to be found about the reasoning behind the implementation that was finally chosen.

Comment: Speaking of which, this reminds me of an old bug in Eclipse that would execute the default case on `null` being passed into it, whereas the specification says that it should throw an NPE.

Comment: If I am not mistaken cases for switch are based on int and to create them java uses hashcodes of strings.

Comment: The link in the OP handles `NULL` before the switch statement is ever reached, you might consider doing likewise.

Comment: @JeffGohlke May be This Q is actually intended to the people who made the language and we are just curious audience ;)

Comment: @JeffGohlke: Just because you didn't make something doesn't mean you don't know why it works the way it does.

Comment: @Mehrdad I completely agree.  That's why *how* questions are answerable.  *Why* questions are not.  Maybe it works that way because the creators were discussing it, then the lead developer spilled some coffee on his pants and got irritated, ending the meeting early.  There is no way to answer a *why* question unless you are the person who made the decision.

Comment: @JeffGohlke: *"There is no way to answer a why question unless you are the person who made the decision."*... well, gparyani's comment proves otherwise

Comment: @Mehrdad No it doesn't. It just moves the question to 'why did they form that judgment?' And it doesn't address the actual question of why there isn't a case null: at all.

Comment: @Pshemo You are mistaken. It is not based on the hashcode. [If one of the case constants is equal to the value of the expression, then we say that the case matches, and all statements after the matching case label in the switch block, if any, are executed in sequence.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) Nothing there about hashcodes.

Comment: @user207421 I can't find it now (since it was 10 years ago), but I remember reading discussion/?information? about how to improve performance in `switch` supporting Strings in comparison to series of `if ("A".equals(s)).. else if("B".equals(s)).. else ...` (where to find proper if-else branch for instance while searching for `"G"`, an application would need to first check `"A"` ... `"F"`). Since already existing at that time switch/case handling *numerical* arguments could find proper case in O(1) time discussion was about converting Strings to numbers which would allow reusing that mechanism.

Comment: @user207421 And hashcode was proposed and accepted. Problem was that hashcodes are not unique, so mechanism would need to use mapping between `hash->listOfMatchingCases` instead of standard `hash->singleCase`. So to find proper `case` from `listOfMatchingCases` the `String#equals` is needed. I am speculating that since hashing is implementation detail related to optimization (which may change in future/updated versions) it was not mentioned in JLS, while usage of `equals` would always be necessary to pick correct `case`, so it was included in JLS. But again that is only my speculation.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

#### Oct 2023 Update

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) [points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263489/why-doesnt-string-switch-statement-support-a-null-case/18263594?noredirect=1#comment136110327_18263594), as of Java 21 a `switch` statement does now support `case null` thanks to [JEP 441](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441). A `NullPointerException` will still be thrown by a switch lacking an explicit `case null` if `null` is passed into it.

Original answer follows:

---

As damryfbfnetsi [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263489/why-string-switch-statment-does-not-support-null-case#comment26786191_18263489) in the comments, [JLS §14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) has the following note:

> The prohibition against using `null` as a switch label prevents one from writing code that can never be executed. If the `switch` expression is of a reference type, that is, `String` or a boxed primitive type or an enum type, then a run-time error will occur if the expression evaluates to `null` at run time. **In the judgment of the designers of the Java programming language, this is a better outcome than silently skipping the entire `switch` statement or choosing to execute the statements (if any) after the `default` label (if any).**

(emphasis mine)

While the last sentence skips over the possibility of using `case null:`, it seems reasonable and offers a view into the language designers' intentions.

If we rather look at implementation details, [this blog post](http://www.riedquat.de/blog/2011-03-04-02) by Christian Hujer has some insightful speculation about why `null` isn't allowed in switches (although it centers on the `enum` switch rather than the `String` switch):

> Under the hood, the `switch` statement will typically compile to a tablesswitch byte code. And the "physical" argument to `switch` as well as its cases are `int`s. The int value to switch on is determined by invoking the method `Enum.ordinal()`. The [...] ordinals start at zero.
>
> That means, mapping `null` to `0` wouldn't be a good idea. A switch on the first enum value would be indistinguishible from null. Maybe it would've been a good idea to start counting the ordinals for enums at 1. However it hasn't been defined like that, and this definition can not be changed.

While `String` switches [are implemented differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338230/697449), the `enum` switch came first and set the precedent for how switching on a reference type should behave when the reference is `null`.

Comment: It would have been a big improvment to allow null handling as part of a `case null:` if it would have been implemented exclusivily for `String`. Currently all `String` checking requires a null-check anyhow if we want to do it correct, although mostly implicitly by putting the string constant first as in `"123test".equals(value)`. Now we are forced to write our switch statement as in `if (value != null) switch (value) {...`

Comment: Re "mapping null to 0 wouldn't be a good idea": that's an understatement since the value of "".hashcode() is 0! It would mean that a null string and a zero length string would have to be treated identically in a switch statement, which is clearly not viable.

Comment: For the case of enum, what was stopping them from mapping null to -1?

Answer (score 40):

In general `null` is nasty to handle; maybe a better language can live without `null`.

Your problem might be solved by

```
    switch(month==null?"":month)
    {
        ...
        //case "":
        default: 
            monthNumber = 0;

    }
```

Comment: Not a good idea if `month` is an empty string: this will treat it the same way as a null string.

Comment: For many cases treating null as empty string can be perfectly reasonable

Answer (score 31):

It isn't pretty, but `String.valueOf()` allows you to use a null String in a switch. If it finds `null`, it converts it to `"null"`, otherwise it just returns the same String you passed it. If you don't handle `"null"` explicitly, then it will go to `default`. The only caveat is that there is no way of distinguishing between the String `"null"` and an actual `null` variable.

```
    String month = null;
    switch (String.valueOf(month)) {
        case "january":
            monthNumber = 1;
            break;
        case "february":
            monthNumber = 2;
            break;
        case "march":
            monthNumber = 3;
            break;
        case "null":
            monthNumber = -1;
            break;
        default: 
            monthNumber = 0;
            break;
    }
    return monthNumber;
```

Comment: I believe doing something like this in java is an antipattern.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski That's pretty much what I meant by "it isn't pretty"

Answer (score 21):

### This is an attempt to answer why it throws `NullPointerException`

The output of the javap command below reveals that `case` is chosen based on the hashcode of the `switch` argument string and hence throws NPE when `.hashCode()` is invoked on null string.

```
6: invokevirtual #18                 // Method java/lang/String.hashCode:()I
9: lookupswitch  { // 3
    -1826660246: 44
     -263893086: 56
      103666243: 68
        default: 95
   }
```

This means, based on answers to [Can Java's hashCode produce same value for different strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102337/javas-hashcode-can-produce-same-hashcode-for-different-strings), though rare, there is still a possibility of two cases being matched (two strings with same hash code) See this example below

```
    int monthNumber;
    String month = args[0];

    switch (month) {
    case "Ea":
        monthNumber = 1;
        break;
    case "FB":
        monthNumber = 2;
        break;
    // case null:
    default:
        monthNumber = 0;
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(monthNumber);
```

javap for which

```
  10: lookupswitch  { // 1
              2236: 28
           default: 59
      }
  28: aload_3       
  29: ldc           #22                 // String Ea
  31: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  34: ifne          49
  37: aload_3       
  38: ldc           #28                 // String FB
  40: invokevirtual #24                 // Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  43: ifne          54
  46: goto          59 //Default
```

As you can see only one case gets generated for `"Ea"` and `"FB"` but with two `if` conditions to check for a match with each case string. Very interesting and complicated way of implementing this functionality!

Comment: That could have been implemented in another way, though.

Comment: I'd say this is a design bug.

Comment: I wonder if this ties in with why some dubious aspects of the string hash function haven't been changed: in general code shouldn't rely upon `hashCode` returning the same values on different runs of a program, but since string hashes get baked into executables by the compiler, the string hash method ends up being part of the language spec.

Answer (score 8):

Long story short ... (and hopefully interesting enough!!!)

Enum were first introduced in [Java1.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29) (**Sep'2004**) and the [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=1223179) requesting to **allow switch on String** was filed long back (**Oct'95**). If you look at the comment posted on that bug at **Jun'2004**, it says `Don't hold your breath. Nothing resembling this is in our plans.` Looks like they deferred (*ignored*) this bug and eventually launched Java 1.5 in the same year in which they introduced 'enum' with ordinal starting at 0 and decided (*missed*) not to support null for enum. Later in [Java1.7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7_.28July_28.2C_2011.29) (**Jul'2011**) they followed (*forced*) the same philosophy with String (i.e. while generating the bytecode no null check was performed before calling hashcode() method).

So I think it boils down to the fact enum came in first and was implemented with its ordinal begin at 0 due to which they couldn't support null value in switch block and later with String they decided to forced the same philosophy i.e. null value not allowed in switch block.

**TL;DR** With String they could have take care of NPE (caused by attempt to generate hashcode for null) while implementing java code to byte code conversion but finally decided not to.

Ref:
[TheBUG](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=1223179), 
[JavaVersionHistory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history),
[JavaCodeToByteCode](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html),
[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/why-cant-i-switch-on-a-string/338230#338230)

Answer (score 1):

According to Java Docs:

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

Since `null` has no type, and is not an instance of anything, it will not work with a switch statement.

Comment: And yet `null` is a valid value for a `String`, `Character`, `Byte`, `Short`, or `Integer` reference.

Comment: @asteri 7 years later, I'd like to point out that `switch` statement doesn't compare instance ref values; it compares instance values.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply that if you use a switch with a reference type (such as a boxed primitive type), the run-time error will occur if the expression is null because unboxing it would throw the NPE.

so case null (which is illegal) could never be executed anyway ;)

Comment: That could have been implemented in another way, though.

Comment: OK @Thilo, smarter people than me were involved in this implementation. If you know of other ways in which this could have been implemented, I would love to know what those are [and I'm sure there are others] so do share ...

Comment: Strings are not boxed primitive types, and the NPE does not occur because someone is trying to "unbox" them.

Comment: @thilo, the other ways to implement this are, what?

Comment: `if (x == null) { // the case: null part } `

Comment: @Thilo: What if the code for `null` and the code for a particular non-null value should do the same thing?  Is there any clean way to avoid repetition?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with insightful comments (Under the hood ....) in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18263594/1053496 in @Paul Bellora's answer.

I found one more reason from my experience.

If 'case' can be null that means  switch(variable) is null then as long as the developer provides a matching 'null' case  then we can argue it's fine . But what will happen if the developer does not provide  any matching 'null' case. Then we have to match it to a 'default' case which may not be what developer has intended  to handle in the default case. Therefore matching 'null' to a default could cause 'surprising behaviour'.
Therefore throwing 'NPE' will make the developer to handle every cases explicitly. I found throwing NPE in this case very thoughtful.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache StringUtils class

```
String month = null;
switch (StringUtils.trimToEmpty(month)) {
    case "xyz":
        monthNumber=1;  
    break;
    default:
       monthNumber=0;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):
>
> > In the judgment of the designers of the Java programming language, [throwing a `NullPointerException` if the expression evaluates to `null` at runtime] is a better outcome than silently skipping the entire switch statement or choosing to execute the statements (if any) after the default label (if any).
>
> - [gparyani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157772/gparyani)   [Aug 15, 2013 at 23:37](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263489/why-doesnt-string-switch-statement-support-a-null-case#comment26786191_18263489)