# Solutions that involve looping over two input arrays: O(n + m) or O(n * m)

Tags: java, time-complexity

I was asked a question in which we're looking for duplicate social security numbers, as in ssn that are in both array A and also array B. My immediate thought was to iterate over each array storing the count of each ssn in a HashMap.Then of course, all keys which have count of more than 1 are duplicates. My understanding was that this would be an O(n + m) operation, where m and n are the number of elements in each array. I was told that this is "very inefficient" in regards to time-complexity and that the time complexity was actually O(n * m). How is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely O(n+m).

Comment: "I was told..." Told by whom? Why does it matter? It sounds pretty strange.  It's linear on average. It's quadratic in the worst case.

Comment: @JoeC that's what I was thinking. How do you correct an interviewer without sounding like a complete tool?

Comment: You are right, it takes `O(n + m)` time. And I believe that is the most efficient it can get.

Comment: @kraskevich can you please explain the quadratic worst case

Comment: @kraskevich by the person conducting the interview

Comment: The right tact to take is to ask the interviewer why he believes that he is right.  Either he will realize his mistake and correct himself, or you will have an opportunity to clarify your answer.

Comment: The quadratic worst case would be if the hash code were absolutely useless in that it put all of the strings in the same hash bucket.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't conisder [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102337/can-javas-hashcode-produce-same-value-for-different-strings)

Comment: So is O(n + m) faster than O(nlogm) ? He wanted me to sort and then use binary search on one of the arrays...? I'm a little confused now. Again, my understanding is that O(n + m) is faster. I'm doubting that I understand anything at this point.

Comment: @ElroyJetson, imo at this point you should stop applying for the position, unless a miraculous explanation is provided by the interviewer.

Comment: @ElroyJetson Sort of array A with `n` values is *O(n* log *n)*, then binary search of all `m` values from array B would be *O(m* log *n)*, which means a total of *O((n+m)* log *n)*, and hence worse than your suggestion, which is *O(n+m)*.

Comment: Hashmap operations are not free. You have to take into consideration the time complexity of hashmap also where you said you will store. Otherwise you will have to do sort and search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `O(n+m)` is faster than `O(n*m)`.  Time complexity of `O(n*m)` is going to be the case when you have two loops like this :

```
for x in [1..n]
   for y in [1..m]
```

So, the term "very inefficient" doesn't apply at all, unless there is a **crunch of extra space** that `O(n+m)` incurs. In that case you can clarify what is the most important factor *time complexity* or *space complexity*.