# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even though plenty of

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am trying to read a 2.5GB txt file into my application.  I am running Win7 x64 and have 43GB of mem available (out of 64GB).  I tried playing around with -Xmx -XX:MaxParmSize -XX:ParmSize etc.  None of these affect the error.  What else could I try?  This error seems very odd as I certainly have enough heap space available.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at j.utilities.IO.loadString(IO.java:187)
    at j.utilities.IO.loadString(IO.java:169)
    at city.PreProcess.main(PreProcess.java:78)
```

I am running

```
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

============== ANSWER ==============

OK, I just tested it with

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ( int i=1; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++ )
    sb.append("x");
```

and got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
...
```

Thus, it really is StringBuilder which tries to build an array bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

In case interested

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i=1;
try {
    for ( ; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++ )
        sb.append("x");
} catch ( OutOfMemoryError e ) {
    System.out.println(i); // OUTPUT: 1207959551
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // OUTPUT: 2147483647
}
```

With StringBuilder you can accumulate 1,207,959,550 chars - far less than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to allocate an array. How many elements does the array have?

Comment: What is the code at `PreProcess.java:78`?

Comment: And what is `j.utilities.IO`? If it is your code paste `IO.java:169`.

Comment: Does StringBuilder internally use an array?

Comment: IO.loadString(IO.java:187) is "sb.append(line);"

Comment: @dotwin yes, should be a `char[]`

Comment: MaxInt is 2.1 billion or so.  You're trying to read in 2.5 billion bytes.  Maybe twice that if it's unicode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to allocate an array that is too large. This is because you're trying to create a very long String. Since arrays are indexed by an integer, an array cannot have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements. Even if the your heap size is very large, you won't be able to allocate an array that has more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, simply because you cannot index its elements using an `Integer`. See [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038392/130224) for more details.

Comment: Does StringBuilder internally use an array?  Or could it be that a String is interpreted as an array of char?

Comment: It should hold a `char[]`.

Comment: Yes StringBuffer/StringBuilder does store its data in an array. But if you are having a string larger then 2GB then you are doing something wrong.\

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new StringBuilder with a size, e.g.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The problem is that you're trying to read a file that's larger than what StringBuilder can have in its array. You have several options, e.g.:

1) Do you really need to read the entire file into memory at once? If so, you'll have to read it into several StringBuilders.

2) Process the file sequentially.

3) Read it into a compressed structure, and uncompress the parts you need when you need them.

Comment: I am using apache camel to read the file , and I think it is internally converting the file into stringbuilder. what can I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the -Xmsn option for the java command.

It specifies the initial size of the memory allocation pool.

Edit: I see you've already done that.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the data in string buffer data is `List<String>` in define interval and clear the `StringBuffer`.