# Solr - Indexer causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, solr

I am using  solr for index as well as content search. When I am try (with 1 GB data and RAM sizes 10 GB for tomcat and solr),
I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ToTextContentHandler.characters(ToTextContentHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler.characters(WriteOutContentHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.MatchingContentHandler.characters(MatchingContentHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.characters(SecureContentHandler.java:270)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.characters(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:146)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.access$001(SafeContentHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler$1.write(SafeContentHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.filter(SafeContentHandler.java:140)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.characters(SafeContentHandler.java:287)
    at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.characters(XHTMLContentHandler.java:278)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser.parse(TXTParser.java:88)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:256)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    SolrHandler.indexFile(SolrHandler.java:218):
```

my code is:--

```
        mData = new Metadata();
        cHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1); or linkedHandler()
        adp = new AutoDetectParser();

        adp.parse(inputStream, cHandler, mData, new ParseContext());
        sid.addField("content", cHandler.toString());
        solrServer.add(sid);
```

Could you pleae tell me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772802/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-even-though-plenty-of