# Read spark dataset only first n columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with more than 5000 columns and OutOfMemoryException was thrown when try to read the dataset, even when limiting to 10 rows. There is another post on the [cause of exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772802/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-even-though-plenty-of) and so I want to read only first n columns to avoid the error. 
I could not find an api call that does that and only the rows could be restricted with `head` or `limit`. 
Is there a way to do restricting to only first few columns? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly did you do (code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your Dataset is `ds`, you can extract the first `n` columns into an Array :

```
val n = 2
val firstNCols = ds.columns.take(n)
```

and then select only these columns from the Dataset :

```
ds.select(firstNCols.head, firstNCols.tail:_*)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

Comment: some documentation on how this works would be nice