# Data row limits on cfspreadsheet

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception, cfspreadsheet

I am loading about 20,000 rows into a `<cfspreadsheet>`. It throws an error:

[image]

When I limit the number of rows to 15,000, I don't get an error.

Is there a hard limit on the number of rows `<cfspreadsheet>` supports?

Comment: Old Excel had a 16384 row limit. Make sure you're using the new file format? (No idea how to do that, but POI does support both, so there should be a way.)

Comment: (Edit) IIRC, just specify an .xlsx extension for the output file. That said, AFAIK, the only row limits are the ones imposed by Excel, [about ~65K for the old binary format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx), which should not matter if you are only exporting 20K rows. But, that error sounds vaguely familiar. How many columns are you exporting? Also, what is the full stack trace of the error message?

Comment: Hmm, just checked and the 16k limit was Excel 95 (also an Access 97 bug). Excel 97 onwards upped it to 65536. (Those are 2^14 and 2^16 btw)

Comment: In addition to row limits, memory limits are also relevant.  Your error message will be something like, "Java heap space exceeded".

Comment: I monitoried the memory usage and there was plenty of free space. I was using Java 7 with G1GC and it reported over 2 GB free

Comment: It would help to see the full stack trace message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similiar to the issue I had here: [How do I fix SpreadSheetAddRows function crashing when adding a large query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921754/how-do-i-fix-spreadsheetaddrows-function-crashing-when-adding-a-large-query). If you have CF10 then you might be in luck 'cause that should be fixed now (as of Update 10 at least).

Comment: In the short term CF 10 is not an option.

Comment: Figured as much, that's why I was explicitly stating CF10. Took me a while to figure out which build was 284725 (where they fixed it) so decided to save everyone the trouble. Really the only other option I'm aware is to rewrite the code to avoid cfspreadsheet use, which no one wants to hear.