# How to process super large xls files with Coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

We have built a spreadsheet parsing app that will allow users to import large amounts of data easily into our application.

We have noticed some clients need in excess of 10,000 - 100,000 lines of spreadsheet data to be imported into the application some times.

Is there a standard practise that any other CF developers use to process large amounts of data within spreadsheets ?

Our standard work around has been to ask the users to break apart their spreadsheets into smaller sub spreadsheets so its manageable.. but Im hoping there is a better solution out there

thanks in advance

Comment: The developer who sits next to me has the same issue. He successfully processes 10 - 20k rows. After that though, he's got issues. I'll look for this question tomorrow and maybe be able to help.

Comment: This question brings back unpleasant memories of java heap space problems.  Depending on the nature of the beast, you might be better off having your clients simply uploading their files.  Then you can have scheduled jobs with database bulk loaders do the heavy lifting.

Comment: This topic may cover some of what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214735/data-limits-on-cfspreadsheet

Comment: took a look at that article, now im curious as to what other options there are other than using cfspreadsheet ? we have used POI when we were on CF 8, and that was full of headaches...

Comment: I you have lots and lots of processing power, consider xlsx. But really you need to move to a formal [tag:ETL] process

Comment: Can you define `super large` ?

Comment: what problem have you run into if you process them all at once? Request timeout? Java out of heap problem?  Can you add more ram?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ColdFusion loop to parse and insert large files instead use native SQL commands such as BULK INSERT (in sql server) and LOAD DATA (in mySQL).

We have process in place that take in, parse large files (more than half million records) and import data into databases without any issue