# After upgrading to ColdFusion 11 from ColdFusion 10 a lot of our reports are generating an error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

After upgrading to ColdFusion 11 from ColdFusion 10 a lot of our reports are generating this error:

```
An exception occurred while calling the function formatRow
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum number of cell styles was exceeded.
```

You can define up to 4000 styles in an .xls workbook. I've went and looked, and we're using it within in a `cfloop` for each and every row we have in our report. Some of these reports can be over 10,000 rows.

```
spreadsheetFormatRow(
    VARIABLES.actions.xls 
    { verticalalignment=""vertical_top"", textwrap=true }, 
    VARIABLES.actions.xls.rowcount
);
```

Comment: The error is very explicit: `The maximum number of cell styles was exceeded`. This is a limit of Excel so not much you can do I'm afraid. The newer version of Excel, .xlsx, allows for 64,000 different styles. Have you tried using .xlsx instead? I'm not sure if the ColdFusion included POI supports that or not. If not, then you may need to look into using a different third party POI and integrating that with ColdFusion.

Comment: Couldn't you format an entire cell range instead of individual rows?

Comment: *we're using it within in a cfloop for each and every row* You should avoid applying separate formats whenever possible. As Miguel-F pointed out, Excel has hard limits on the total styles allowed. While CF's implementation is a black box, calling that function on every row means it is *very* likely CF will create a new "style" each time, greatly increasing the likelihood you will blow out the limit when working with a large number of rows. Whenever possible, try and reduce the number of cell styles required by formatting a range of cells, as Dan suggested.

Comment: This question is similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214735/data-row-limits-on-cfspreadsheet