# making an array of bigInteger of size biginteger in java

Tags: java, biginteger

i am trying to make an array of biginteger of size biginteger.

```
public class Polynomial4   
{  
private BigInteger[] coef;      
private BigInteger deg;   
public Polynomial4(BigInteger a,BigInteger b)   
{  
coef =  new BigInteger[b+1];// here its giving the error   
coef[b] = a; // here also its showing error *  ///required int found Biginteger  

}    

}
```

please help me....thanks in advance....

Comment: It makes no sense to use a BigInteger for the size of an array. The maximum theoretical size [is about Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size) (although most systems can't even create arrays that big)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)** has an [**intValue**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29) method. which converts BigInteger into an int primitive.arrays expect an int as its size while BigInteger is an object.

```
    coef =  new BigInteger[b.intValue()+1];
       coef[b.intValue()] = a;
```