# How to use BigInteger value to initialize String Array?

Tags: java

I am writing a program and stuck with below issue of BigInteger.

```
BigInteger noOfCombinationForWordsToBeSearchedBig = factorial(noOfWordsToBeSearched);
String[][] combinationForWordsToBeSearched = new String[ noOfCombinationForWordsToBeSearchedBig.longValue()][noOfWordsToBeSearched];
```

I want to initialize the `String[][]` array with value of `noOfCombinationForWordsToBeSearchedBig` .

For examaple, i am finding factorial of 17 which is big integer.

Please advise.

Comment: Even if Java allowed you to initialize an array this big, do you have enough ram to store 17!=355687428096000 pointers to String? Assuming each pointer is 8 byte, you'd need 2845TB of RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array index can not be more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in Java. In fact its much less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. So actually you can not put `BigInteger` as the size parameter, while creating an array.

For details [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size).

Comment: Thanks. forgot this concept.