# Why is the output showing error for the value of int?

Tags: java

```
class lab1{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int arr[]= new int[2147483647];
        System.out.println(arr.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you post code that produces an error, post that error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as the error states, that the array is too big:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at lab1.main(lab1.java:7)
```

This is because there is a set maximum size of arrays in Java.

For more information, you should see: [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)