# Max size of byte array with which String object can be formed?

Tags: java, gwt, arrays

I am trying to create a String object from a byte array like below:

```
String content = new String(byteContents);
```

The size of the byteContents array is 200,000 approx. I get the following error when the above line is encountered.

```
stack: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

If I try it with a byte array of size say 10,000, I don't get such an error. Is there a limit on the maximum size of the byte array that can be passed as an argument to the String constructor?

Comment: You can put the number less than integer maximum limit i.e. Intefer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: I've never seen ```stack: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded``` in Java; that would be a ```StackOverflowError```, but it wouldn't happen with that code. Are you using Javascript somewhere in the mix?

Comment: Its GWT actually. It converts the java to javascript. Added the tag as part of the question now.

Comment: It looks like either Javascript or GWT is storing byteContents in stack memory. I'd have to see the generated JS code to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of the byte array is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Is there something you're trying to do with the String itself that you're not showing us that could be causing this problem?

Comment: It's actually *slightly* lower, but by just a few bytes.

Comment: geoffrey-tucker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size