# What is the maximum length of an array in Go, Java and C#?

Tags: java, c#, go

What is the maximum length of an array that I can declare in Go, Java and C#? Does it relate to the maximum memory at runtime? Or do they have a standard?

Comment: In java, the `length` of an array is an `int` field, so the max length of an array is determined by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: ..and is similar in .NET with `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Appears to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3039805/3558960)

Comment: This is some information on the max array limit for C#. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen well, that answer is from 2010, so I would have to test it on JAva 8 and with more memory dedicated to the JVM and check if it gives the same error.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It does on recent Oracle Java 8 JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Array types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)
>
> An array is a numbered sequence of elements of a single type, called
>   the element type. The number of elements is called the length and is
>   never negative.
>
> The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a
>   non-negative constant representable by a value of type `int`.
>
> [Numeric types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> A numeric type represents sets of integer or floating-point values.
>
> There is a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint     the set of all unsigned integers, either 32 or 64 bits
> int      the set of all signed integers, same size as uint
> ```

Go array length is a value of type `int`, which is a 32 or 64 bit signed integer, depending on the compilation architecture (GOARCH), for example, 386 or amd64. It's also subject to any hardware or operating system memory size limits.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("int is", strconv.IntSize, "bits on", runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

Output:

```
int is 64 bits on amd64
```