# Maximum length of String[]

Tags: java, string

I have a long `String` and I want to parse it using array of strings like this:

```
String data = ... very long String delimited by spaces...
String[] parse = data.split(" ");
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4617
```

Is it possible, that maximum length of String array is 4617 ?

Comment: No it isn't.  Not sure, possibly an exception from the regex in `String.split()`?  We might be able to help you more with the full stack trace of that exception.  One line doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Why don't you add a couple of more words delimited by spaces and call `parse.length()`?.

Comment: Please add the whole stacktrace.

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? You should get a line number where the exception occurs. It's not occurring in the code you showed.

Comment: i try to reproduce it. i have a string with 5000+ words and the split works and a can read the array. your problem must be on an other place.

Comment: Omg, I've found trivial error in my code, but thanks for your answers!

Comment: @gaffcz can you share with us so we can learn?

Comment: @gaffcz - You have chosen the wrong answer. The correct answer is *as much as your JVM allows*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum length of an string array in Java is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`. (Checked with my 64-bit OS with this initialization: `String[] myStringArray = new String[Integer.MAX_VALUE-5];`.
 `Integer.MAX_VALUE-4` or bigger numbers gives me `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error. The limit can be different for you, since it is machine and OS dependent).

Even if you go beyond that, you will see `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, not `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The problem is definitely with other part of your code.

Comment: ya nice answer I feel something is wrong with the op code.

Comment: You're right, I've found trivial error in my code, omg :-( thank you

Comment: @gaffcz can you share with your error with us plz?

Comment: Where is it specified that its `Integer,MAX_VALUE - 5`?

Comment: @TheLostMind look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size

Comment: @KickButtowski - That answer is wrong.. I am getting OME for `Object[] o = new Object[Integer.MAX_VALUE-80];` . Don't accept whatever you see here as right.. Think logically. The answer also depends on the behaviour of GC, heap space allocated etc.

Comment: @TheLostMind what you mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski - look at the comment to the question.

Comment: @TheLostMind The answer depends on the JVM, but in your case it's probably just the fact that you do not have enough memory.

Comment: @CL. -Please look at my comment *for* the question.

Answer (score 1):

use enchance for loop to iterate over parse..Somewhere else in your code you had used wrong index for parse

```
for(String s:parse){
 System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.. There is no max length for the size of an Array. Although you might run into an `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i=0;i<10000000000l;i++){
        sb.append(i).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString().split("\\s").length);
}
```

The above code *might* give `OutOfMemoryError` on some machines (it did on mine. tried it with jdk 6)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        sb.append(i).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString().split("\\s").length);
}
```

The above code works fine and prints 1000

Comment: The size of an array can't exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, since the language specifies the size of an array as `int` type. The actual limit can be lower, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Where have they mentioned it?

Comment: [JLS 8.0 - Section 15.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) `Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.` The length of an array can only be `int` type.