# Is there a limit of the number of aliases (globally and/or per index) in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm starting to study elasticsearch for my project. 
Specifically version 1.5.
I'm considering using aliases to abstract client apps from the intricacies of index setup.
I might end up with 20 to 50 indexes and 10 to 30 aliases per indexes.
This would amount to 1500 aliases.

I wonder if there is a limit in the number of aliases per indexes and or per cluster.

Thanks in advance,

P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elasticsearch source code I see aliases are referenced as `String[]`. And arrays in Java [seem to have quite a large size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size) and I wouldn't worry about 1500 aliases :-).

What I would worry about, though, is the cluster state. Elasticsearch nodes share between them the entire cluster state which contains all the mappings, all the aliases, templates etc. A large cluster state means more data to be moved around on the network and more time to process/ingest the updated cluster state. 1500 aliases doesn't sound too bad.