# How can I use BigInt/Long as type of size in Vector.sparse of spark?

Tags: scala, vector, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have to deal with a lot of data, and I use spark.

Now I try to use `Vectors.sparse` to generate a large vector of features, but the feature size may exceed 4 billion, above max of int, so I want to use BigInt or Long type to deal with it.

But I read code and document that `Vectors.sparse` support int as size type only, why limit it to int? And how can I bypass this limit?

Answer (score 0):

> why limit it to int?

Because [~ `Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039805/1560062) is a hard limit of the size of the Java array. Since sparse vectors use arrays to store indices an values it simply cannot be larger.

> And how can I bypass this limit?

Rather unlikely unless you want to rewrite `SparseVector` implementation. In practice having billions of features (how do you get there?) means much more serious problem. Not all operations on vectors preserve sparsity not to mention most of the linear algebra libraries cannot handle that like this.

Comment: Yes, I read the code and I realize that I need a few days to modify it.

Comment: 2. Our app has above 10 millions of users, and hundreds of topics(like tech, military, etc.), I want to know user's favorite topics, so I cross users and topics (~10 million * ~400). Am I wrong? I don't have much experience for this subject, please point out if I am wrong.

Comment: A natural representation in this case would be a matrix with 10M rows / 400 columns + some algorithm like ALS. I don't see any use for a single vector of length 100M * 400...

Comment: Yes, this may be the result (model weights) to user, but I need to train the model by using users' visit logs, and the original input is like "label, user, item, topic", the after-cross input is like "label, user, item, topic, user x topic"

Comment: My ultimate purpose is to estimate ctr on any item, so I use the crossed feature, and I've trained model per user before, the topic feature for a single-user-model is effective, so I want to cross the feature and use it here.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Suppose we have users (Jack, Joe), items (a, b, c, d, e), topics (x, y, z). Note that items are 1 to n topics. We have logs before crossed the features: (1, Jack, a, x), (0, Jack, d, z), (1, Joe, d, z), (1, Joe, a, x), and the first one (1, Jack, a, x) equals to one-hot vector (1, (1,0), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0))

Comment: The real labeled vector should be (1, (1,0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)) when training. And notice that the data is big, I chose LR(L-BFGS) to train the model, so it can only deal with linear relations, which is ineffective when there are all categorical features, so I want to add (user cross topic) as a feature, and it would be `(1, Jack, a, x, Jack*x), (0, Jack, d, z, Jack*z), (1, Joe, d, z, Joe*z), (1, Joe, a, x, Joe*x)`. The feature (user cross topic) represents one specified topic's influence of a user.

Comment: And the one-hot vector after crossed: (1, (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0) ++ (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), equal to `(1, Jack, a, x, Jack*x)`

Comment: I'll take a look at this tomorrow and I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: Fix: items are 1 to 1 topics, each item has only one topic. But topic is much less, around 400, however, item's number is above 100 thousand.