# Fastest way to run out of memory

Tags: java

I came up with the following method. I am getting a stackoverflow error. Is there a faster way?

```
static void looper(){
        long a = 0;
        a++;
        System.out.println(a);
        looper();
    }
```

Comment: `static void loper(){loper();}`? Why?

Comment: When you want to get a `StackOverflowError`, then just call `looper` as the first statement. No need to create, increatement and print `a`.

Comment: If you just want to run out of memory, why not just allocate a _massive_ array?

Comment: @Tom thanks. Makes sense.

Comment: @ajshort Massive array?

Comment: @Bathsheba Well was an interview question and this is my answer. Seems I got it wrong.

Comment: StackOverflowError is not the same as OutOfMemoryError. You should say fastest way to run out of stack frames / memory :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Hm seems I totally got it wrong then. What would be fastest way to hit OutOfMemoryError then. I am trying to find fastest way to run out of memory.

Comment: @JasSy - Well, if the interviewer meant *any memory*, then the answers posted above (in comments) are right. Else just keep creating objects and keep adding to them to a List in a loop to get OutOfMemory (heap-space)

Comment: @TheLostMind So guess something along the lines of List<Integer> ls = new List(); while(true){ls.add(1);} Thanks.

Comment: @JasSy - Well.. I would prefer `ls.add(new Integer("1"))` to make things faster. Integer class keeps a local cache of values between -128 to 127. Why not just create new `Runnable` instances and add them to the List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast way to get an `OutOfMemoryError` is:

```
final int[] memoryGrave = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

*(You can find more about max array sizes in this question: [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size))*

But this *might* not be what you're looking for, since it is possible that the JVM checks the requested array size and throws that error *before* actually running out of memory.
But you can alter that code a bit, to do that "correctly":

```
final List<int[]> memoryGrave = new ArrayList<>();
while(true) {
    memoryGrave.add(new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5]);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

But if this is *"fastest way"* to get that error (and really run out of memory) can still be discussed.

---

When you wrap the above code into a `try/finally`, then you can measure the time it needs to throw that error:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
    final List<int[]> memoryGrave = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        memoryGrave.add(new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5]);
    }
} finally {
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
}
```

On my machine it needs round about *30 ms*.