# How many integers can an array in java and python have?

Tags: java

How many integers can an array in java and python have? And if I want to enter more integers to an array and I reached that limit how to handle this?

Comment: Java: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3038392/715593

Comment: You know, answering this question with google needs probably less time than you spent writing up the question ... just keep in mind that there are many "basic" things around; and you should get used to dig into existing material yourself.

Comment: Side note: if you have to deal with more than 2^31 elements, maybe an array isn't automatically the best data structure to use. I guess then you might want to consider a data structure that is optimized for the kind of computation you want to do.

Comment: This is actually *two* questions. One about java and the other about python. I'm calling this a dupe for java. Search/ask another about python if you want the answer for that language.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays can have 2^31-1 element in theory, although some JVM cannot allocate an object larger than 2^31-8 elements due to OS limitations. (See the ArrayList code for an example of this limit in practice)

If you have more elements, you can either

- have an array of arrays.
- use a memory mapped file to store the data.  This has the advantage of potentially greater than main memory and is persisted.