# Int Tally Max Number Java

Tags: java, int

I would just like to know what the highest number is that I can put in place of x:

```
int[] tally = new int[x];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

Comment: Your `x` can hold `INT_MAX` at the max which is `2^31 - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically put in Integer.MAX_VALUE since that is the highest integer value you can have. But it depends on how much RAM you have, for example if you have 2 billion numbers you would need at least 32 bit * 2 billion = 8 GB of RAM and that is just for the array itself. So you could pick a number like a million and that should do for you.

Answer (score 0):

A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, (2 in power of 31)-1, but that would be horrendously huge array that would use huge amount of memory. It's hard to think of a use case where you'd need such a thing. If you are thinking about creating such a monstrosity - most likely something is wrong with your design.