# What is the limit of BINARY data types in Hive 1.2?

Tags: hive, apache-hive

I did not find much about `BINARY` data types in apache docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types

I created a table with `BINARY` column using-

```
create table table1(col1 binary);
```

After fetching metadata via JDBC I found,

> columnSize:2147483647

Is there any official document for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Binary DataType Proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Binary+DataType+Proposal) :

> **How is 'binary' represented internally in Hive**
>
> Binary type in Hive will map to 'binary' data type in thrift.
>
> Primitive java object for 'binary' type is ByteArrayRef
>
> PrimitiveWritableObject for 'binary' type is BytesWritable

And since [ByteArrayRef](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/ByteArrayRef.html) holds a reference to a byte array, the answer should be `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039805/2037229)