# Fibonacci n modulo m

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, fibonacci

I'm trying to compute  **modulo , where  may be really huge: up to 10^18 ,  is n-th Fibonacci number**
Here's my code , it works well for small numbers but for big numbers it is throwing OutOfMemoryError or NegativeArraySizeException.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FibonacciHuge {
private static long getFibonacciHugeFast(long n, long m) {
long[] arr = new long[(int) n + 1];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
arr[i] = (arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]) % m;
}
return arr[(int) n];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
long n = scanner.nextLong();
long m = scanner.nextLong();
System.out.println(getFibonacciHugeFast(n, m));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the first say 10 numbers in the sequence?

Comment: Array sizes would seem to be bound by `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size) discusses.  Using `10^18` as the value of `n`, which is _much_ larger than `2^32`, should cause an error.

Comment: You may not need array to calculate the nth fibonacci number. Try `private static long getFibonacciHugeFast(long n, long m) {
  long first = 0;
  long second  = 1;
  long value = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
   value = (first + second) % m;
   first = second;
   second = value;
  }
  return value;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of your two exceptions/errors.

1. OutOfMemoryError exception: Due to the fact you're trying to create an array that is HUGE, well past the possible size. Refer to this question [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)
2. NegativeArraySizeException: Due to the fact you're casting a long into an integer (the code `long[] arr = new long[(int) n + 1];`). Read this: [Primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). (Basically you're overflowing at some point and the resulting integer is a negative number)

Answer (score 1):

If `n` can be **10^18**, then even if you don't use an array, it will still time out, as you are going to run a loop till `n` (which is **10^18**) to calculate the nth fibonacci number.

You can use the matrix exponentiation method (linear recurrence method). You can find detailed explanation and procedure in [this](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/) blog. Run time is `O(log n)`.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code

1. You only need to know fibonacci elements n-1 and n-2 in order to compute element n, so you don't need an array but just two variables.
2. You can compute the n-th element modulo m from the n-1 and n-2 elements modulo m, since (a + b) % m == (a % m + b % m). In fact, you wouldn't be able to store the 10^18th fibonacci number in a long, since its value is huge - the fibonacci sequence grows exponentially.
   The only issue you might have with this is if a % m + b % m overflows, so you should limit m to be Long.MAX_VALUE / 2, since you don't know how large the actual element will be just from knowing n. Or alternatively you could add an overflow check in your function.