# Maximum string length for Java EE security roles names

Tags: jakarta-ee, security-roles

There is a limit in the maximum length of Java EE security roles names ( for example one of the names used in the @DeclareRoles and @RolesAllowed annotations) ?

I would like to have some references to standards or RFC that possibly puts a limit (or not ) in the length security roles names? Is the same for Java EE 5, Java EE 6, Java EE 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no constraints in the spec. This is not explicitly said, but the absence of explicit constraint makes it like there are none.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-intro005.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/security/DeclareRoles.html

Note that specific implementations like Wildfly, Weblogic, Glassfish, etc. might have constraints. You should check with your AS.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little research I found that the maximum value of an array in java is determined by **Integer.MAX_VALUE - 4** wherein **MAX_VALUE** is *2 ^ 31-1*.

You can take a look at the following response in SO: [Do Java arrays Have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html