# Unable to initialize Boolean array using long value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, boolean, long-integer

What I am trying to do is initialize Boolean array and size of the array is long value.

```
public static  List<Integer> primesUpTo(long target) {

         boolean[] nonPrime = new boolean[target];

}
```

I am getting following Error:

```
possible loss of precision
         boolean[] nonPrime = new boolean[target];
                                          ^
  required: int
  found:    long
```

Can someone explain me please why I am unable to initialize Boolean array using long value and also I am unable to increment long value say for : boolean[] nonPrime = new boolean[target+1] also not working.Thanks for advance.

Comment: read the error - arrays can only be declared using an int value.  If you can guarantee that `target` will fit into a `int` then cast it.  Otherwise you are probably going to run out of memory.

Comment: Arrays are always initialized with an `int`. You can not make an array larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a language limitation.

> Java has been criticized for not supporting arrays of more than 2^31−1 (about 2.1 billion) elements.[17][18][19] This is a limitation of the language; the Java Language Specification, Section 10.4, states that:
>
> > Arrays must be indexed by int values... An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error.[20]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays

Answer found here: [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size).

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. I appreciate your approach to give information. I wonder people giving negative marking rather try to answer question.