# Maximum size of 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I have to create 1000 heaps, each of which can contain 10^6 nodes. For easy access of the nodes, for deletion of nodes and for updating keys of nodes, I am planning to create a 2D array of size 10^6 * 1000 in which I'll be storing the references of nodes. But, is an array of such a big size possible to create in Java? 
Is there a better way to access a particular node from the heaps without creating an array? 
I could go through each node of the heap in order to search for my node, but this process will be of the order n for 1 heap, and if I have to perform a deletion of a particular node from all heaps, the process would take be of the order 1000*n.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays are indexed by `int`s, so the maximum index is `2^31 - 1`, which is 2147483647 (approx. 2E9), so you should be ok with your 1E9 sized array. However, you'll need to have enough RAM, don't forget a billion `long`s will take 8GB of ram.

There's a much more detailed discussion in [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

Answer (score 0):

If you need more memory than max value of int you can use sun.misc.Unsafe. See here: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe