# What is the max capacity of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, capacity

I know that the initial capacity of an ArrayList is 10. When this limit is exceeded, a new ArrayList is created with the capacity of `(oldcapacity * 3 / 2) + 1`, and the elements are copied over.

But what is the **maximum** capacity of an ArrayList?

I was asked this question in an interview. The interviewer was not interested in the default initial capacity, but wanted to know the maximum capacity of an ArrayList.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is a `List` implementation backed by an array - so, you're actually asking what's the largest array you can create. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size for some discussion on this.

Comment: You need to define what language you are talking about

Comment: why is this question not getting an answer???

Answer (score 3):

Look in the source code:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
    } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    }
}
```

and you will see the relevant part here:

```
this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
```

so the array list can at most so many elements as an array can hold.

the next question may arise: ***but then, how many elements can hold an array?***

the answer is: it depends on what VM are you writing the code:

in JDK8:

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

where

```
 /**
 * A constant holding the maximum value an {@code int} can
 * have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.
 */
@Native public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;
```

Comment: This is a great example of how to give an answer on SO. Thanks for taking the time to do this right.