# Iterate array if index range is in long

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, long-integer

how to iterate through array/ list in Java. if index range is in long. As array/list only accept integer in position index.

eg

```
long arr[]=new long[5];
for(long i=0l;i<5l;i++)
     arr[i]=i;  // throw an error as arr[i] only accept integer
```

here `arr[i]` will throw an error because i is of type `long` and array takes input as `integer` in index location.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You can't. Array indices are limited from `0` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` by design. If you need to access more elements you should think about a different data structure that does not use one array internally. You can use `LinkedList` (or other `List`s) or multiple arrays. But if you really need to manage that much objects in **one datastructure** this probably is a **XY problem** and you should think about rethinking your approach.

Comment: Note that if your `long` values represent valid integer values you can always cast to `int` and then use the value as index.

Answer (score 2):

The size limit<sup>1</sup> on arrays is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so an array index that is a `long` makes no sense.

A `List` can have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, but indexing it will be problematic because `List::get` takes an `int` argument.

So, you will struggle to use either arrays or lists (implemented using `List`) for really large data structures.

The solution ... if you really need one ... would be to implement your own `List` class with overload or alternative for operations that expose the size and indexing.  It would not be trivial.

Another (possibly simpler) approach would be to represent your `long[]` as a `long[][]` and map the subscripts.

Finally, if you are using `long` as a subscript unnecessarily (i.e. the indexes don't need to go beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), then:

```
   long arr[] = new long[5];
   for (long i = 0l; i < 5l; i++) {
       arr[(int) i] = i; 
   }
```

---

<sup>1 - This is the theoretical maximum size.  1) You may get an `OutOfMemoryError` if you attempt to allocate an array that large.  The JVM needs at least `length * size(<type>)` bytes of free contiguous storage to allocate an array of `<type>` of length `length`, where `size(<type>)` is the size of a primitive type or a reference.  2) In a 32 bit JVM, you are also limited by the address space dimensions.  3) In recent Hotspot JVMs, the largest array that you can allocate is actually `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5` elements: see [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is Integer.MAX_VALUE? Would it be more correct to say that the max size of an array depends on memory od virtual machine? When trying to initialize array with Integer.MAX_VALUE I get OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Arrays are limited by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Of course, your memory is always a factor. It's a large value, such an array needs to allocate space for `2 Mrd` objects. Even if the objects are only `10 Byte` big (unrealistic small) it would already need `20 GB` of memory.

Comment: I have addressed this in the footnote.  It is actually a bit more complicated than that ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the index to be `long` even if your array consists of `long's`. Change it to

```
for(int i = 0; ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Narrow the `long` to an `integer` by a cast `arr[(int)i] = i;`
2. Change the type of `i` to an `integer` and let the compiler widen it for you when it is assigned `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) arr[i] = i;`

As you cannot map all long values to a integer the compiler will *not* automatically narrow a variable. As you can map all integer values to a long the compiler will widen a variable automatically for you.