# Java buffer indexed by long instead of int?

Tags: java

It looks like all java containers, buffers, arrays and etc, can only be indexed by int. On C++, I can index by `unsidned long` for example.

What is the solution for this in Java? I can surely create my own class that uses lots of int32 indexable buffers and access the rigth one, but is there a better and simpler way?

Comment: No, there isn't -- unless your array is particularly sparse, in which case a `Map` might work.

Comment: Why do you want to use long to index in Java anyway? It depends on the architecture of the language and I don't think Java can support that big of an index.

Comment: There's no simpler way; it's baked into the JVM. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038392/438992, which I found by searching the web for "java maximum array length" or something similar.

Comment: I have been perusing the language spec and I could not find anything that specifically indicated the maximum size (although there is sufficient information about other array aspects to conclude it must be an int >= 0).

Answer (score 3):

According to the Java language specification.

[10.4 Array Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4)

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6) and become int values.

> An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error.

And from my own perspective, since the `Array.length` returns an `int`, there would be no need to have an index beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  So indexing via a long wouldn't be necessary.