# What is the largest array // collection in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, kotlin, collections

I came across an interesting problem on codewars, solved it in a similar way, but it gives an error:

> "Arrays length between 200,000 and 250,000".

I didn't find an answer in the network, I decided to ask here.

```
fun sumParts(ls: IntArray): IntArray {
    if (ls.isEmpty() == true){
        var results = ls.toMutableList()
        results.add(0)
        return results.toIntArray()
    }
    var returnArr = ArrayList<Int>()
    var count: Int = 0
    var results = ls.toMutableList()
    while(count != ls.size){
        var sum: Int = results.sum()
        returnArr.add(sum)
        results.removeFirst()
        count += 1
    }
    if (returnArr.last() == 0){
        var arr: IntArray = intArrayOf(0)
        return arr
    }else{
        returnArr.add(0)
    }
    return returnArr.toIntArray()
}
```

Comment: on which line are you getting the error?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "Arrays length between 200000 and 250000". The assignment said:Take a look at the performance: some lists contain thousands of items.
I want to find out which array (collection) contains this amount of data

Comment: Dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)?