# how many profiles can we define in spring application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

Just for my curiosity, I wanted to know how many profiles we can define or how many profiles does spring boot support ?

I tried looking into official document of spring, but didn't find any clue. [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: As many as you can fit in memory and as many as you are prepared to wait for while loading and checking. I doubt there's a hard limit.

Comment: *Theoretically* a full `String[]` ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038392/592355

Comment: (it would be a nice load test..to see that context!) But as a "rule of thumb", i'd recommend: #profiles << #beans

Comment: @xerx593, String[] holds integer datatype for size so you mean 2^32 ?