# Confluent Schema Registry - maximum number of schemas

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I'm referring to the [Confluent Schema Registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry):

Is there reliable information on **how many distinct schemas a single schema registry can support**?

From how I understand the schema registry, it reads the available schemas on startup from a kafka topic.

So possible limitations could be memory consumption (= amount of schemas in memory at a time) or performance (= lookup of schemas from Kafka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own benchmark tool for finding about possible limitations.
Link to Github repo is [here](https://github.com/thilo-behnke/schema-registry-benchmark).

**TL;DR:**

As suspected by @OneCricketeer, the scalability factor is the ~ `nr of schemas * size of avg schema`. I created a tool to see how the registry memory and cpu usage scales for registration of many different AVRO schemas of the same size (using a custom field within the schema to differentiate them).
I ran the tool for ~48 schemas, for that ~900 MB of memory where used with low cpu usage.

**Findings:**

- The ramp up of memory usage is a lot higher in the beginning. After the intial ramp up, the memory usage increases step-wise when new memory is allocated to hold more schemas.
- Most of the memory is used for storing the schemas in the ConcurrentHashMap (as expected).
- The CPU usage does not change significantly with many schemas - also not the the time to retrieve a schema.
- There is a cache for holding RawSchema -> ParsedSchema mappings (var `SCHEMA_CACHE_SIZE_CONFIG`, default 1000), but at least in my tests I could not see negative impact for a cache miss, it was both in hit and miss ~1-2ms for retrieving a schema.

**Memory usage (x scale = 100 schemas, y scale = 1 MB):**

[image]

**CPU usage (x scale = 100 schemas, y scale = usage in %):**

[image]

**Top 10 objects in Java heap:**

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name (module)
-------------------------------------------------------
   1:        718318       49519912  [B (java.base@11.0.17)
   2:        616621       44396712  org.apache.avro.JsonProperties$2
   3:        666225       15989400  java.lang.String (java.base@11.0.17)
   4:        660805       15859320  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node (java.base@11.0.17)
   5:        616778       14802672  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue (java.base@11.0.17)
   6:        264000       12672000  org.apache.avro.Schema$Field
   7:          6680       12568952  [I (java.base@11.0.17)
   8:        368958       11806656  java.util.HashMap$Node (java.base@11.0.17)
   9:         88345        7737648  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node; (java.base@11.0.17)
  10:        197697        6326304  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node (java.base@11.0.17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, it uses a `ConcurrentHashMap` to store that information, so, in theory, the limit is roughly the max size of a backing Java array.

[Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)

However, there are multiple maps, and therefore, JVM heap constraints will also exist. If you have larger raw-schema strings, then more memory will be used, so there is no good calculation for this.

Comment: Interesting way of looking at that. So basically the upper bound is 32 - 2 = 30 bit because of the way schemas are stored in maps and because a 32 bit Integer is used for storing schema ids. For a rough calculation of heap memory the number of schemas times an estimated avg size could be used (plus some unknown factor for other heap memory).

Comment: Schema texts are md5 hashed, and compared, so that math would be for unique schemas, not necessarily number of subjects, or matching versions between subjects